# python 3.6.9 lock screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, ubuntu

I would like to make a simple script in python to lock my screen when the key "c" is pressed.
When I run:

```
$ python3
import os
os.popen("dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock")
```

it works, but when I make a simple loop the command won't lock my screen but just swap my desktop with an unused window.

```
import os
import keyboard
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while(True):
        if keyboard.is_pressed('c'):
            os.popen("dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock")
```

I have already tried `os.popen('gnome-screensaver-command --lock')`
edit : and with `subprocess.run()`,
do no work with a `break` or `sleep` to

So how can I lock my screen with python3?
Maybe I'm missing something or have a bad command.

Here my ubuntu version information:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: Probably the keyboard activity interferes with the screen locking program. Why are you using `os.popen()` here? Probably look at `subprocess.run()` instead. (Not the reason it's failing, though.)

Comment: i have already try with `subprocess.run() ` my apologies i forgot to say it.
and i have the same issue

Comment: it's not a good idea to use a busy loop; and because you can't press the key in just an instant, the command might be sent multiple times, which can cause problems.

Comment: I think it's possible to use a timer to sleep for a while (until the key is released) before sending the command.

Comment: well , i can add a sleep(0.5) but the probleme here is not i have many call to my screen lock but the screen lock doesn't work.
And when i add a `break` the command is send just one time but that doesn't work to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found some solution with i3lock
you con found i3lock [here][1]

and use like : `subprocess.run("i3lock")`
[1]: https://i3wm.org/i3lock/